# Object pool with the ability save objects on exit and reload on start?

Tags: java, object-pooling, apache-commons-pool

[Apache Commons seems to be the decent Object Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) implementation out there. Or any other framework that could support the cause

How Can I save its state of the pool during shutdown; may be serialize its objects to a external form json, xml ..? and reload during next startup ?

Comment: Saving is not part of a Pooling framework's job. The main job is reusing resource/time intensive objects without creating them. If you want this feature however you can write your own implementation.

Comment: I added a [test-case](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/trunk/yapool/yapool-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/yapool/statefull/TestSaveRestore.java) to Yapool (also an Object Pool implementation) which shows resources can be saved/restored. But you are on your own when it comes to persisting and loading these resources (e.g. to XML/json file).

Comment: @vanOekel wow this is exactly what I was looking for. can you write this as an answer, so I can reward you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to capture objects in a pool when the pool is closed and put these objects back in the pool when a pool is opened with [Yapool](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/). I added a [test-case](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/trunk/yapool/yapool-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/yapool/statefull/TestSaveRestore.java) to Yapool that shows how this could be done.

Persisting these objects "between pools" is not part of Yapool. But you can, for example, store them in a file and load them before a pool is opened.

Update: added [another test-case](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/trunk/yapool/yapool-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/yapool/statefull/TestCRPool.java) which shows a more proper implementation and also shows a corner-case.